# Omit instances of an invalidated nested many field in Marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

In [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is it possible to omit instances of a nested schema that fail validation without failing the parent? For example, an Atom feed can have many entries. If one entry is missing required fields, can that entry be omitted so that the feed and its correctly parsed entries pass validation without the failed entry?

```py
from marshmallow import Schema


class Feed(Schema):
    """Atom/RSS feed."""
    ...
    entries = fields.Nested('Entry', many=True)
    ...

class Entry(Schema):
    """Article of an Atom/RSS feed."""
    ...
    title = fields.String(required=True)
    link = fields.Url(required=True)
    ...
```

Before validating Feed

```
...
"entries": [
  {
    "title": "Title A",
    "link": "http://httpbin.org/status/200"
  },
  {
    "title": "",
    "link": "",

  },
  {
    "title": "Title C",
    "link": "http://httpbin.org/status/200"
  },
]
...
```

After validating Feed

```
...
"entries": [
  {
    "title": "Title A",
    "link": "http://httpbin.org/status/200"
  },
  {
    "title": "Title C",
    "link": "http://httpbin.org/status/200"
  },
]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pre_load](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.decorators.pre_load) decorator can be used to filter nested fields, but I assume each nested schema is deserialized twice: once during pre_load and once during load.

```py
class Feed(Schema):
    ...
    entries = fields.Nested('Entry', many=True)
    ...

    @pre_load
    def filter_entries(self, data, **kwargs):
        schema = Entry()
        filtered = []
        for entry in data['entries']:
            try:
                filtered.append(schema.load(entry))
            except ValidationError:
                continue
        data['entries'] = filtered
        return data
```